# Showing information in scatterplot using a color spectrum

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, colorbar, colormap

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Given data
x_values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
y_values = np.array([4, 6, 3, 5, 7, 6])
information = np.array([
    [0.3, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1],
    [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5],
    [0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1],
    [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1],
    [0.0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2]])
```

I have x and y values and some information to show using color on a scatter plot. Each of the column from the information array represents 5 parameters for each (x,y) point. I want to show the participation of those parameters using a spectrum of color. How can I do it?

Comment: The desired result is not clear: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHYc8.png)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney This is my interpretation: OP has 6 points in _x-y_ plane, and associated to each point 5 parameters (a column in `information`) , and the sum of a column is always one. Then the OP asks for a method to represent this 4-way dependency using "a spectrum of color" — I have to say that, if my understanding is correct, there is no obvious way to do that.

Comment: that is right interpretation @TrentonMcKinney

Comment: @gboffi could you suggest what would be the best way of visualizing such parameters?

Comment: @gboffi my understanding is that there is simply no way to represent 4 degrees of freedom in a color spectrum. You only have 3 colors to work with. Our eyes can't perceive more than that.

Comment: @Joooeey I have posted a solution that stretches the Idea of "a spectrum of color", let's see if the OP appreciates...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a reasonable solution, using [`mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d.html#mpl-toolkits-mplot3d-axes3d-axes3d-bar3d)

[image]

As you can see, there is a nasty artifact..., <strike><strike>further there is (so it seems) a Matplotlib bug that prevents adding a legend, that is sorely needed (see [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344145/explain-the-error-produced-using-plt-legend-in-a-3d-stacked-bar-plot)).</strike></strike> I've added the sorely needed legend using the info [Trenton McKinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7758804/trenton-mckinney) provided in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344145/explain-the-error-produced-using-plt-legend-in-a-3d-stacked-bar-plot#comment134624727_76344145) — thank you Trenton.

Here it's the code, the only trick is how the `bases` array is computed

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
y = np.array([4, 6, 3, 5, 7, 6])
informations = np.array([
    [0.3, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1],
    [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5],
    [0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1],
    [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1],
    [0.0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2]])

bases = np.vstack(([0]*len(x), informations.cumsum(axis=0)))[:-1]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for n, (base, info) in enumerate(zip(bases, informations)):
    ax1.bar3d(x-0.5, y-0.5, base, 1, 1, info, label=str(n), shade=True)

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')

color = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']()
proxies = [plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, **next(color)) for _ in informations[:,0]]
labels = 'Apricots Bananas Cherries Dates Elderberries'.split()
ax1.legend(proxies, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.50), loc='center left', frameon=0)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I was thinking in similar way. Thanks for your answer.